# How to stop empty form fields from being submitted in Liferay 5.2.3?

Tags: liferay

When the form is submitted, I get the empty fields with zero value as well. I want to receive only the filled fields. Using LR 5.2.3.

Thanks in advance! 
Adia

---

UPDATE (Web form's view.jsp file):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(
        function() {
            jQuery('#<portlet:namespace />fm').submit(
                function() {
                    var keys = [];
                    var fieldLabels = {};
                    var fieldOptional = {};
                    var fieldValidationErrorMessages = {};
                    var fieldValidationFunctions = {};
                    var fieldsMap = {};

                    <%
                    int fieldIndex = 1;
                    fieldLabel = preferences.getValue("fieldLabel" + fieldIndex, StringPool.BLANK);

                    while ((fieldIndex == 1) || Validator.isNotNull(fieldLabel)) {
                        fieldOptional = PrefsParamUtil.getBoolean(preferences, request, "fieldOptional" + fieldIndex, false);
                        String fieldType = preferences.getValue("fieldType" + fieldIndex, "text");
                        String fieldValidationScript = preferences.getValue("fieldValidationScript" + fieldIndex, StringPool.BLANK);
                        String fieldValidationErrorMessage = preferences.getValue("fieldValidationErrorMessage" + fieldIndex, StringPool.BLANK);
                    %>

                        var key = "<%= HtmlUtil.escape(fieldLabel) %>";

                        keys[<%= fieldIndex %>] = key;

                        fieldLabels[key] = "<%= HtmlUtil.escape(fieldLabel) %>";
                        fieldValidationErrorMessages[key] = "<%= fieldValidationErrorMessage %>";

                        function fieldValidationFunction<%= fieldIndex %>(currentFieldValue, fieldsMap) {
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test='<%= Validator.isNotNull(fieldValidationScript) %>'>
                                    <%= fieldValidationScript %>
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>

                     jQuery(this).children(':input[value=""]').attr("disabled", "disabled");

                                    return true;
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                        };

                        fieldOptional[key] = <%= fieldOptional %>;
                        fieldValidationFunctions[key] = fieldValidationFunction<%= fieldIndex %>;

                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test='<%= fieldType.equals("radio") %>'>
                                fieldsMap[key] = jQuery("input[name='<portlet:namespace />field<%= fieldIndex %>']:checked").val();

                                if (!fieldsMap[key]) {
                                    fieldsMap[key] = '';
                                }
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                fieldsMap[key] = jQuery("#<portlet:namespace />field<%= fieldIndex %>")[0].value;
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>

                    <%
                        fieldIndex++;
                        fieldLabel = preferences.getValue("fieldLabel" + fieldIndex, "");
                    }
                    %>

                .
                .
                .
            );
        }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to stop a form from submitting fields with no values is to use Javascript to control the form submission, iterate through all the form fields and build a data object to post to your form.  Otherwise, all fields will be submitted.  This can get complicated if you have different types of form fields (selects, radios, checkboxes, etc.) so it's actually easier and better to just have your form processing controller check for blank/null values.

Comment: Yes JavaScript is the best option, but is not the easiest way to go about it. Using  3rd party JavaScript library like jQuery to do the heavy lifting is much better. With jQuery you can validate all fields and not worry about building a "data object"

Comment: Actually I am also trying to control this with JavaScript. So as you can see in my update above, I have added this line '          jQuery(this).children(':input[value=""]').attr("disabled", "disabled");' to stop submitting empty fields, but can't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend jQuery Validate which you can find here:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

It's easy to use, and is great for validation of any web form. I've used it to validate all the forms I've created in portlets with Liferay. Out of the box it provides a lot of scope for validation like empty fields, email addresses etc but gives you the flexibility to create your own rules!

Check it out as it's cleaner, easier, and better than standard JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is more complicated to understand. I am giving code which i use for validation form in Liferay with jquery validation.

This is normal form:

```
<form action='<portlet:actionURL/>' method="post" id="frmPin">
        <table id="pinTable">
            <tr>
                <td width="170px">
                    Email:
                </td>

                <td>
                    <form:input path="model.userEmail" type="email" id="userEmail"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="170px">
                New Pin:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="model.pin" maxlength="4" type="number" id="pin"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="btnResetPin" value="Reset PIN" name="resetPin"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

And Jquery Validation code in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#btnResetPin").click(function(){
    jQuery("#frmPin").validate({
        rules : {
            userEmail : "required",
            pin : {
                required : true,
                maxlength: 4,
                minlength: 4
            }
        },
        messages : {
            userEmail : {
                required: "Please enter the Email Address"
            },
            pin : {
                required: "Please enter the PIN",
                maxlength : "Please enter 4 digits PIN",
                minlength : "Please enter 4 digits PIN"
            }
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

This will help with required and fix length input. You can add many more with jquery validation.

and for enable jquery validation in your portlet you have to add fllowing tag in your liferay-portlet.xml before `</portlet>` tag.

```
<header-portlet-javascript> http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js </header-portlet-javascript>
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks.